# Dimensionality Dilemma: Dimensional Analysis Invalidates my Mathematical Model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, units, dimensional-analysis, angular-velocity

I am trying to derive an equation that describes the rotational motion of an "auto-unravelling system": systems comprised of a material (string, chain, cloth etc.) wound around a cylinder and left to unwind under the weight of the hanging segment of material.

[image: My derivation so far]

Everything up until the red text is correct dimensionally speaking. The issue arises when I attempt to get rid of the *$\frac{dl}{dt}$* term: the rate of change in the length of chain left on the roll.  I want to put in terms of angular displacement (theta).

Note that my unravelling system is composed of small chained beads wrapped around a toilet roll in such a way that we can assume each full turn to be a loop of beads.  Thus the entire system is just a series of concentric loops.

The issue is that the dimensions of *$\frac{dl}{dt}$* are *$\frac{metres}{second}$* but the dimensions of *kwR* (*w*-omega being angular velocity) is *$\frac{radian*metres}{second}$* (*k* is simply an error coefficient to account for error between calculated length under the aforementioned assumption and empirical length)

**QUESTION: How do I augment my equation so that the dimensions match up or do I need to find another way to describes $\frac{dl}{dt}$ in terms of omega?  If a new method is required could you point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite see any problems with dimensions: radians are dimensionless.

Comment: so the dimensions of *w* is just 1/s ?

Comment: @AniekanUmoren : Yes, the dimension of angular veloсity is 1/s.